# Цикл доходит до 9 и дальше не добавляет

Tags: python, while

Вот код:

```
    a=1
    b=1
    ruskie=['а','б','в','г','д','е','э','ж']
    print(len(answer))
    trueanswer=[]
    while a<(len(answer)-1): 
        if answer[a] in ruskie:
            if answer[a-1]==' ' and answer[a+1]==' ':
               print('dadadadaaadad')
               trueanswer.insert(b,answer[a])
               b=b+1
               a+=1
        else:
            a+=1
```

Цикл останавливается на значении а=9 б=2, должен доходить до значения длинны переменной"answer" и в переменную"trueanswer" выдавать буквы, возле которых два пробела.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if answer[a] in ruskie:
        if answer[a-1]==' ' and answer[a+1]==' ':
           a+=1
```

если вы вошли в первое условие, но не вошли во второе, то у вас вообще вечный цикл будет

зачем тут использование `while`, когда напрашивается обычный проход по буквам строки через `for`:

```
for a in range(1, len(answer) - 1):
```

без использования внутри цикла `a += 1`